# IMPORTXML returning #NA [resource at url not found] and #NA [imported content is empty] in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I've been working on a google sheet that uses IMPORTXML to extract multiple data from different URLs in column N of same sheet. most of the data are imported correctly in the required cells but some cells are returning **#NA [resource at url not found]** and some are returning **#NA [imported content is empty]** I've tried all I can to no avail.

This is one of the formulas returning #NA [resource at url not found].  It is supposed to import **kategoria** from   https://www.tim.pl/gniazdo-do-przekaznikow-serii-60-13-88-02-modulow-czasowych-86-90-03smaa

=IMPORTXML(N13;"//ul[@class='breadcrumbs__list theme--light']//li[5]//a//span")

This is one of the formulas returning #NA [imported content is empty].      It is supposed to import **kategoria** from https://www.tim.pl/wyszukiwanie/wyniki/?q=60.13.8.230.0040&p=1&category=ALL&query=60.13.8.230.0040&dir=desc&order=p3m&limit=24

=IMPORTXML(N12;"//ul[@class='breadcrumbs__list theme--light']//li[5]//a//span")

This is the link to the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q7IV_i--1artQMzqx3O-7YGqe-_HDljCRm8bFX4tsRc/edit?usp=sharing

i would appreciate every single help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value of `kategoria` from the URLs of `https://www.tim.pl/###` using IMPORTXML.

When I saw the URL of `https://www.tim.pl/gniazdo-do-przekaznikow-serii-60-13-88-02-modulow-czasowych-86-90-03smaa`, it seems that the value of `kategoria` is not seen because of the status code of "404". By this, `#N/A` is returned.

It seems that there is no `div` with the class of `breadcrumbs__list theme--light` in the URL of `https://www.tim.pl/wyszukiwanie/wyniki/?q=60.13.8.230.0040&p=1&category=ALL&query=60.13.8.230.0040&dir=desc&order=p3m&limit=24`. By this, `#N/A` is returned.

I thought that in this case, it might be required to use the common XPath for your URLs for retrieving your expected value. For this, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=IFERROR(IMPORTXML(B1;"//div[@data-categories-trail or contains(@class,'layout product-box')][1]//div[./span[text()='Kategoria:']]/a"))
```

- In this case, the URL is put in the cell "B1".

#### Testing:

When this sample formula is used for your provided URLs in your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

- In this case, when the value of `kategoria` is not found, the empty value is returned.

#### Note:

- In this sample formula, your provided URLs are used. So, when you use other URLs, this sample formula might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- From your question of `It is supposed to import kategoria from URL`, this sample formula retrieves the value of `kategoria`. So, when you want to retrieve other values, please post it as a new question.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)